# Stuck with crash dump analysis - user32!NtUserSetFocus freezes app?

Tags: windbg, postmortem-debugging

We have an old VB6 application that keeps freezing and/or crashing. We setup an easy shortcut for users to create a full dump when the program freezes.

We now have a week's worth of dumps, and most of them show a cryptic stack from the hung thread, which doesn't even include any of our functions, and the last call is to user32!NtUserSetFocus.

We're really stuck here... can anyone help?

```
0:000> kb
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0018d788 755eee3e 002609ac 00000001 755eed34 user32!NtUserSetFocus+0x15
0018d7a0 755962fa 00260f22 00000110 002609ac user32!MB_DlgProc+0x10a
0018d7cc 755bf9df 755eed34 00260f22 00000110 user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
0018d848 755bf784 00000000 755eed34 00260f22 user32!UserCallDlgProcCheckWow+0xd7
0018d898 755bf889 0160cf70 00000000 00000110 user32!DefDlgProcWorker+0xb7
0018d8b8 755962fa 00260f22 00000110 002609ac user32!DefDlgProcW+0x29
0018d8e4 75596d3a 755bf860 00260f22 00000110 user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
0018d95c 7559965e 00000000 76ee3d54 00260f22 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x109
0018d9a0 755c206f 0160cf70 00000000 76ee3d54 user32!SendMessageWorker+0x581
0018da74 755bcf4b 75580000 00000008 00000000 user32!InternalCreateDialog+0xb9f
0018daac 755ef73c 75580000 1736f6a8 0010193a user32!InternalDialogBox+0xc1
0018db60 755efa18 00000030 ffffffff ffff0000 user32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x757
0018dcb8 755efc65 0018dcd0 00000000 755efbd1 user32!MessageBoxWorker+0x269
0018dd38 729af829 0018dd50 0010193a 0010193a user32!MessageBoxIndirectA+0x94
0018dd78 729af6a5 0018ddbc 00000000 00000000 msvbvm60!VBMessageBox2+0x92
0018dda0 729af9a0 729af7ce 0018ddbc 0018ddbc msvbvm60!MessageBoxPVoid+0x4b
0018ddd0 729a3d68 00000000 12aa8ef8 0018ddf8 msvbvm60!DlgEnableModeless+0x5e
0018de34 729a3db6 032807d4 002308e4 00000030 msvbvm60!_Scanint+0x13
0018de54 72a0c411 174be0e4 00000000 00000030 msvbvm60!RefMemberIDFromHxmod+0x39
0018de70 72a0c6f3 174be0e4 00000000 00000030 msvbvm60!EbShowError+0x3
0018de94 72a2497c 010831b8 00000000 00000000 msvbvm60!GetErrMsg+0x90
0018deb0 770fb6ad 0018df9c 00000000 0018dfec msvbvm60!SehUpdateStack+0x29
0018ded4 770fb67f 0018df9c 0018f6f8 0018dfec ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
0018def8 770fb620 0018df9c 0018f6f8 0018dfec ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24
0018df84 770b0163 0018df9c 0018dfec 0018df9c ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x127
0018df84 74f3c42d 0018df9c 0018dfec 0018df9c ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
0018e4a0 72a10dcf c000008f 00000001 00000002 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
0018e4c0 72a0e228 010831b8 800a0061 0018e584 msvbvm60!CEnumConPnts::QueryInterface+0x34
0018e4d4 72a0e28c 010831b8 00000000 00000000 msvbvm60!BasicExcepDeferredFillIn+0x65
0018e4e4 72a0be99 00000061 11035a85 00000000 msvbvm60!BasicExcepDeferredFillIn+0xd2
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 msvbvm60!ValidateArray+0xb4
```

!runaway proves that this is indeed the hung thread.

```
0:000> !runaway
 User Mode Time
  Thread       Time
   0:ca8       0 days 0:01:00.325
   8:13a4      0 days 0:00:00.171
   6:10b4      0 days 0:00:00.062
  10:1554      0 days 0:00:00.031
  19:1598      0 days 0:00:00.000
  18:a88       0 days 0:00:00.000
  17:7b0       0 days 0:00:00.000
  16:ba0       0 days 0:00:00.000
  15:770       0 days 0:00:00.000
  14:103c      0 days 0:00:00.000
  13:16bc      0 days 0:00:00.000
  12:17e4      0 days 0:00:00.000
  11:1160      0 days 0:00:00.000
   9:1194      0 days 0:00:00.000
   7:dc8       0 days 0:00:00.000
   5:1510      0 days 0:00:00.000
   4:af0       0 days 0:00:00.000
   3:e5c       0 days 0:00:00.000
   2:10f4      0 days 0:00:00.000
   1:ff8       0 days 0:00:00.000
```

!analyze -hang -v produces the following:

```
0:000> !analyze -hang -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
GetUrlPageData2 (WinHttp) failed: 12152.

FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

CONTEXT:  00000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
eax=00000001 ebx=00000000 ecx=00000000 edx=00000000 esi=0018dcd0 edi=00260f22
eip=755a218a esp=0018d788 ebp=0018d7a0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00200246
user32!NtUserSetFocus+0x15:
755a218a 83c404          add     esp,4

FAULTING_THREAD:  00000000

BUGCHECK_STR:  HANG

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG

PROCESS_NAME:  OurProcess.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff - <Unable to get error code text>

EXCEPTION_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xcfffffff - <Unable to get error code text>

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  OurProcess.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.16384 (debuggers(dbg).130821-1623) x86fre

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
OS Thread Id: 0xca8 (0)
Current frame: 
ChildEBP RetAddr  Caller, Callee

DERIVED_WAIT_CHAIN:  

Dl Eid Cid     WaitType
-- --- ------- --------------------------
   0   758.ca8 Unknown                

WAIT_CHAIN_COMMAND:  ~0s;k;;

BLOCKING_THREAD:  00000ca8

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  APPLICATION_HANG

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 755eee3e to 755a218a

STACK_TEXT:  
0018d788 755eee3e 002609ac 00000001 755eed34 user32!NtUserSetFocus+0x15
0018d7a0 755962fa 00260f22 00000110 002609ac user32!MB_DlgProc+0x10a
0018d7cc 755bf9df 755eed34 00260f22 00000110 user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
0018d848 755bf784 00000000 755eed34 00260f22 user32!UserCallDlgProcCheckWow+0xd7
0018d898 755bf889 0160cf70 00000000 00000110 user32!DefDlgProcWorker+0xb7
0018d8b8 755962fa 00260f22 00000110 002609ac user32!DefDlgProcW+0x29
0018d8e4 75596d3a 755bf860 00260f22 00000110 user32!InternalCallWinProc+0x23
0018d95c 7559965e 00000000 76ee3d54 00260f22 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x109
0018d9a0 755c206f 0160cf70 00000000 76ee3d54 user32!SendMessageWorker+0x581
0018da74 755bcf4b 75580000 00000008 00000000 user32!InternalCreateDialog+0xb9f
0018daac 755ef73c 75580000 1736f6a8 0010193a user32!InternalDialogBox+0xc1
0018db60 755efa18 00000030 ffffffff ffff0000 user32!SoftModalMessageBox+0x757
0018dcb8 755efc65 0018dcd0 00000000 755efbd1 user32!MessageBoxWorker+0x269
0018dd38 729af829 0018dd50 0010193a 0010193a user32!MessageBoxIndirectA+0x94
0018dd78 729af6a5 0018ddbc 00000000 00000000 msvbvm60!VBMessageBox2+0x92
0018dda0 729af9a0 729af7ce 0018ddbc 0018ddbc msvbvm60!MessageBoxPVoid+0x4b
0018ddd0 729a3d68 00000000 12aa8ef8 0018ddf8 msvbvm60!DlgEnableModeless+0x5e
0018de34 729a3db6 032807d4 002308e4 00000030 msvbvm60!_Scanint+0x13
0018de54 72a0c411 174be0e4 00000000 00000030 msvbvm60!RefMemberIDFromHxmod+0x39
0018de70 72a0c6f3 174be0e4 00000000 00000030 msvbvm60!EbShowError+0x3
0018de94 72a2497c 010831b8 00000000 00000000 msvbvm60!GetErrMsg+0x90
0018deb0 770fb6ad 0018df9c 00000000 0018dfec msvbvm60!SehUpdateStack+0x29
0018ded4 770fb67f 0018df9c 0018f6f8 0018dfec ntdll!ExecuteHandler2+0x26
0018def8 770fb620 0018df9c 0018f6f8 0018dfec ntdll!ExecuteHandler+0x24
0018df84 770b0163 0018df9c 0018dfec 0018df9c ntdll!RtlDispatchException+0x127
0018df84 74f3c42d 0018df9c 0018dfec 0018df9c ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher+0xf
0018e4a0 72a10dcf c000008f 00000001 00000002 KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58
0018e4c0 72a0e228 010831b8 800a0061 0018e584 msvbvm60!CEnumConPnts::QueryInterface+0x34
0018e4d4 72a0e28c 010831b8 00000000 00000000 msvbvm60!BasicExcepDeferredFillIn+0x65
0018e4e4 72a0be99 00000061 11035a85 00000000 msvbvm60!BasicExcepDeferredFillIn+0xd2
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 msvbvm60!ValidateArray+0xb4


FOLLOWUP_IP: 
msvbvm60!VBMessageBox2+92
729af829 8bd8            mov     ebx,eax

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  e

SYMBOL_NAME:  msvbvm60!VBMessageBox2+92

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: msvbvm60

IMAGE_NAME:  msvbvm60.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4a5bda6c

STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s ; kb

BUCKET_ID:  HANG_msvbvm60!VBMessageBox2+92

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_HANG_cfffffff_msvbvm60.dll!VBMessageBox2

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:application_hang_cfffffff_msvbvm60.dll!vbmessagebox2

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {e6dc63dc-251f-a6d5-c66e-f5e07e418955}

Followup: MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: This stack is displaying a message box (user32!MessageBoxIndirectA) for an unhandled exception (ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher) with code c000008f. A bit of googling reveals it's VB code for an "internal exception code" (source: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/232829). I'd even say it might be an "unimplemented COM interface" error since msvbvm60!CEnumConPnts::QueryInterface seems to be the source of the exception.

Comment: @deemok - thank you, this helps A LOT. So if I understand this correctly, at the memory location msvbvm60!CEnumConPnts::QueryInterface+0x34, a call is made to KERNELBASE!RaiseException, passing c000008f as the first param. KERNELBASE!RaiseException then continues until KERNELBASE!RaiseException+0x58, where it calls ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher, and so on?

Comment: If you inspect the argument to MessageBoxIndirectA you can retrieve the message itself - which will give clues as to what the problem is.

Comment: That's amazing, @deemok - calling ds on the first param to MessageBoxIndirectA produced question marks, but calling it on the command before, VBMessageBox2, produced the incredibly helpful "Run-time error '97': Cannot call friend function on object which is not an instance of defining class". So this is the result of msvbvm60!CEnumConPnts::QueryInterface... the only problem is that I still don't know what params were passed to QueryInterface...

Comment: I'm not sure if `MSGBOXPARAMSA` is a public symbol, but if you used `dda 0018dd50`, you would've probably gotten the same message. There might be more info in the exception record: `.exr 0018dfec`. And either `010831b8` or `800a0061` is a GUID pointer in the call to `QueryInterface`.

Comment: I tried reading 010831b8 and 800a0061 using ds, dS, da, du... nothing worked...

Comment: I can only suggest that you upload the dump(s) (maybe not the original but stripped ones - you can strip the original dump by writing a new one from it using `.dump /m`) somewhere to have a look.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly I'd find out what it's doing. When it hangs get a couple of crash dumps and compare the stacks to find out where exactly it's spinning. Also some of the symbols have large offsets (user32!InternalCreateDialog+**0xb9f**), are you using a symbol server?

Comment: I am using MS symbol server and my own symbol files, but I don't obviously have symbols for user32.

Comment: Offsets don't look too large for me. There are also lots of different method names, so IMHO it's fine. See `lm m user32` and check whether it shows `private` symbols.